# How to save changes to float formatting in the Spyder variable explorer?

Tags: spyder

'Save and Close' option cannot be selected even after the changes have been made in the float formatting section. Please help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! To help others understand and answer your question, consider expanding on the question—giving a detailed explanation of the current outcome and your desired outcome. Feel free to include images if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The *Save and close* button is only made active after you manually change a value of your Numpy array or Dataframe. Since changing the float formatting of numbers only modifies its display and not its contents, there's no need to make *Save and close* active.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Do I have to manually changing the float formatting every time I wish to see the Dataframe in a particular format? Is there a way to default it to something like %.0f ?

Comment: The default is the last format value you selected. We don't offer more than that, sorry.